# Unable to install wx

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, cabal

I failed to install cabal:

```
$ cabal install wx
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/wxc-0.90.1.1-30692/wxc-0.90.1.1/Setup.hs, /tmp/wxc-0.90.1.1-30692/wxc-0.90.1.1/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/wxc-0.90.1.1-30692/wxc-0.90.1.1/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring wxc-0.90.1.1...

  Warning: No config found to match: /usr/bin/wx-config --version=2.9 --version-full
           in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/config
  If you require this configuration, please install the desired
  library build.  If this is part of an automated configuration
  test and no other errors occur, you may safely ignore it.
  You may use wx-config --list to see all configs available in
  the default prefix.

readProcess failed: readProcess: wx-config "--version=2.9" "--version-full" (exit 1): failed
setup: failed
Failed to install wxc-0.90.1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wx-0.90.1.0 depends on wxc-0.90.1.1 which failed to install.
wxc-0.90.1.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
wxcore-0.90.1.1 depends on wxc-0.90.1.1 which failed to install
```

Before this I did and they installed without errors:

```
 apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev
 apt-get install libglu-dev
 apt-get install g++
```

I also ran `$ cabal update`

How do I fix this?

Comment: In case you haven't looked this already, this may help you: http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2

Comment: @Sibi, I've added sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0/ubuntu/ trusty universe' and made apt-get update but still there was the same error after all of this.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue in Linux while installing wxc 0.92, and managed to resolve this by manually fixing some issues with my wxWidgets 3.02 installation.

Specifically, the wxHaskell's setup file calls wx-config. Try this in your terminal or shell: `wx-config --release` should report 3, and `wx-config --version=3.0` should complete without any messages at all. Look in `/bin/` folder, there should be a `wx-config` file. This is a script file; edit it. You will see that it points to `/usr/lib64/wx/config/gtk2-unicode-release-2.9` or something like that. Change this to point to a version 3.0 file: it could be in the `/usr/local/lib/wx/config/` folder. If you cannot find the file, try installing `wxWidgets` from source rather than from binaries package.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. To solve this problem, you just need to install wxWidgets before using cabal to install wx.

https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets